# vim edit mode - How to open a file and go to a line number

Tags: vim

In edit mode, how do I specify vim to go to a specific line(say 67)?
The following command treats line number as file name.

```
:e /tmp/foo 67
```

I know how to do this when starting vim, but that's incovenient when you're already inside an editing session with other files.

```
vim /tmp/foo +67
```

Comment: It's not elegant, but `:e /tmp/foo` followed by `67G` is what I would typically do.

Comment: It looks like `:e +67 /tmp/foo` works just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While perfectly correct and canonical (see `:help +cmd`), OP's solution of putting the line number before the file name never felt right to me because it doesn't map with how I think: directory > file > line.

Therefore, I prefer to do:

```
:e /tmp/foo|67
```

which lets me deal with the file first, then with the line, which is much more intuitive to me.

Note that both `:e +67 /tmp/foo` and `:e /tmp/foo|67` do exactly the same thing under the hood:

```
:e /tmp/foo
:67
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @larsks and @romainl for the answers!

```
:e +67 /tmp/foo
OR
:e /tmp/foo|67
```